# Update all rows of TableA with id returned by Insert in TableB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, let's say `campaigns`, to which I want to add a foreign key referencing a record in a table I just created: `statistics`. I want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint on `campaigns.statistic_id`, so I need to first create one `statistics` record for each `campaigns` record, update `campaigns` to set the `statistic_id` (one for each `campaigns` record), then add the constraint.

I can't find a clean way to generate N `statistics` records, where N is equal to `count(*) from campaigns`, and right after this `INSERT` do an `UPDATE` on the `campaigns` table to set the `statistic_id` fk.

**What I have so far** is the following (**but is not working**, syntax error around the `insert`):

```
update campaigns
set statistic_id = tmp.id
from (
  insert into statistics default values -- basically 0 for all columns
  returning id
) tmp;
```

**We found a workaround** but I feel like there must be a better way to achieve this. Basically our (working) workaround is:

```
insert into statistics select id from campaigns;
update campaigns set statistic_id = id;
select setval('statistics_id_seq', (select max(id)+1 from statistics), false);
```

But `statistics.id` is poorly fed and can contain "gaps" between each `id` instead of being normally incremented (see SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c7580/2). **There must be a better** way to achieve this.

I am using PostreSQL v9.6. The foreign key must be in the `campaigns` table (because we will have several tables references to this `statistics` table and don't want to have composite foreign keys).

Comment: try declaring a variable, then setting it equal to scope_identity() after your insert and updating with that - scope_identity() will automatically populate with the most recent identity column value added to your table after insert - this works in sql server not sure about PostreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this will do what you want:

```
insert into statistics (id)
    select row_number() over (order by id)
    from campaigns;

update campaigns
    set statistic_id = c.s_id
    from (select c.*, row_number() over (order by id) as s_id
          from campaigns c
         ) c
    where campaigns.id = c.id;
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cddad/1).

Comment: Thank you sir! It fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, we have _tons_ of campaigns and the execution time may take around 1 sec. If there was a campaign created between the `insert` and the `update`, then the newly created campaign(s) would try to reference a non-existing `statistics` record. I will backup this with a `trigger` + `function` in order to automatically create a `statistics` record on `campaign` insert + add a where clause for the update `where campaigns.statistic_id is null`.